# Is there a setting in MS Exchange that enables a warning when a repeating booking is made over a weekend?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2013, outlook-2010

There was a time when people didn't care when repeating meetings were booked over the weekend. No one would be around to care.

But now that people have smartphones plugged into their work calendar, repeating meetings flash alerts on the weekend for non-existent meetings.

My question is: **Is there a setting in MS Exchange that enables a warning when a repeating booking is made over a weekend?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a specific way to warn about repeating bookings outside work hours but you can restrict meetings to only during work hours, see [set-calendarProcessing](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd335046%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx).